# Transition com tempo diferente ao passar o mouse (hover) e ao retirar

Tags: css, css-transições

Tenho uma imagem onde eu faço um `transition scale` com `hover`, dando um zoom na imagem ao passar o mouse:

```css
img{
   width: 200px;
   height: 100px;
   transition: transform .5s ease;
}

img:hover{
   transform: scale(1.5);
}
```

```html
<img src="https://www.cleverfiles.com/howto/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/mini.jpg">
```

O tempo da transição é de meio segundo (`.5s`), mas eu gostaria que na volta (ao tirar o mouse sobre a imagem) ela demorasse o dobro do tempo para voltar ao tamanho original, ou seja, 1 segundo.

É possível fazer isso apenas com CSS? Ou como faria isso por outro meio?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Já tentou definir a propriedade de `transition` nos dois estados do css, uma com mais e outra com menos tempo?

Veja no seu próprio exemplo, ao ativar o `hover` reduzo o tempo de transição:

```css
img{
   width: 200px;
   height: 100px;
   transition: transform 5s ease;
}

img:hover{
   transform: scale(1.5);
   transition: transform 1s ease;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://www.cleverfiles.com/howto/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/mini.jpg">
```

Nota: Exagerei um pouco nos valores para deixar a diferença nítida.

Comment: Legal cara. Era isso mesmo que eu tava atrás. ObG!