# Atrasar o fechamento de um dropdown

Tags: javascript

Existe uma maneira, alternativa, mais lite, ao superfish, para atrasar o fechamento de um menu dropdown? Quando o menu está em hover, ele obviamente abre, e quando o mouse não está mais focado nele, o menu fecha. Gostária de ter um atraso no fechamento desse menu. Algo semelhante ao ao superfish.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**PS EDIT**

Encontrei algo semelhante ao que é pedido na pergunta, com algumas considerações. É o [Unhover Intent in JS](https://codepen.io/team/css-tricks/pen/myLByd) do CSS-TRICKS, que funciona até certo ponto. Não funciona com mais de um dropdown. O que pode ser feito para que ele se torne mais eficiente é: O Dropdown deve manter o delay, inclusive no dropdown do dropdown. Mas o delay deve terminar caso o mouse vá para outro item da nav principal.

```css
#primary_nav_wrap
{
 margin-top:15px
}

#primary_nav_wrap ul
{
 list-style:none;
 position:relative;
 float:left;
 margin:0;
 padding:0
}

#primary_nav_wrap ul a
{
 display:block;
 color:#333;
 text-decoration:none;
 font-weight:700;
 font-size:12px;
 line-height:32px;
 padding:0 15px;
 font-family:"HelveticaNeue","Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif
}

#primary_nav_wrap ul li
{
 position:relative;
 float:left;
 margin:0;
 padding:0
}

#primary_nav_wrap ul li.current-menu-item
{
 background:#ddd
}

#primary_nav_wrap ul li:hover
{
 background:#f6f6f6
}

#primary_nav_wrap ul ul
{
 display:none;
 position:absolute;
 top:100%;
 left:0;
 background:#fff;
 padding:0
}

#primary_nav_wrap ul ul li
{
 float:none;
 width:200px
}

#primary_nav_wrap ul ul a
{
 line-height:120%;
 padding:10px 15px
}

#primary_nav_wrap ul ul ul
{
 top:0;
 left:100%
}

#primary_nav_wrap ul li:hover > ul
{
 display:block
}
```

```html
<nav id="primary_nav_wrap">
<ul>
  <li class="current-menu-item"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li class="has-children"><a href="#">Sub Menu 2</a>
          <ul class="sub-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Schiller</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Gogol</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Nietzsche</a></li>
              <li class="has-children"><a href="#">Schoppenhauer</a>
                <ul class="sub-menu">
                  <li><a href="#">Linspector</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Shakespeare</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Andrade</a></li>
                  <li class="has-children"><a href="#">Code Geass</a>
                    <ul class="sub-menu">
                      <li><a href="#">Shingeki No Kyojin</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Shisekai yori</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">No game no life</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">One Punch Man</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Nanatsu no Tasai</a></li>
                    </ul>
                  </li>
                  <li><a href="#">Tolstói</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Platão</a></li>
                </ul>
              </li>
            <li><a href="#">Dostoievski</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Immanuel Kant</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
  <li><a href="#">Deep Menu</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Sub Menu 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Sub Menu 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Sub Menu 3</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Sub Menu 4</a>
      
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Deep Menu 1</a>
            <ul>
              <li><a href="#">Sub Deep 1</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Sub Deep 2</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Sub Deep 3</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Sub Deep 4</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Deep Menu 2</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Sub Menu 5</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Menu 2</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Sub Menu 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Sub Menu 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Sub Menu 3</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Menu 3</a>
    <ul>
      <li class="dir"><a href="#">Sub Menu 1</a></li>
      <li class="dir"><a href="#">Sub Menu 2 THIS IS SO LONG IT MIGHT CAUSE AN ISSEUE BUT MAYBE NOT?</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Category 1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Category 2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Category 3</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Category 4</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Category 5</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Sub Menu 3</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Sub Menu 4</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Sub Menu 5</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>

</ul>
</nav>
```

**Referências**

https://codepen.io/team/css-tricks/pen/myLByd

https://css-tricks.com/dropdown-menus-with-more-forgiving-mouse-movement-paths/

http://benalman.com/code/projects/jquery-dotimeout/examples/hoverintent/#1b

https://superfish.joelbirch.co/examples/

Comment: Já tentou usar o `transition` especificando o delay como [**neste exemplo**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/306907/transition-com-tempo-diferente-ao-passar-o-mouse-hover-e-ao-retirar/306913#306913)? Não funciona para você?

Comment: @DiegoRafaelSouza Já tentei isso, mas não é tão eficiente, a não ser se for com algumas condicionais. O atraso do dropdown deve terminar. No momento em que o mouse for movido para outro item da navegação.

Answer (score 2):

Fiz um exemplo que tem um *delay* de `500ms` antes do menu fechar. Deixei comentado no CSS onde vc muda esse tempo para mais ou para menos. Tb tive que mudar o estilo dos *sub-menu* de `display:none/block` para `scaleY()` mas visualmente não terá diferença.

Repare que eu criei algumas classes apenas para *dar nomes aos bois* e vc poder entender melhor *(usar classes tipo: #menu ul li ul ul {estilos} pode ser BEM confuso!)* Então crie classes com nomes tipo `.pai` `.filho` `.neto` `.bisneto` e fiz os estilos com `transition` e `delay` repare que agora apenas os submenus tem um pequeno *delay* depois que vc tira o mouse, no entanto os itens principais continuam com `display:none/block` e sem *delay*

```css
        #primary_nav_wrap {
            margin-top: 15px
        }

        #primary_nav_wrap ul {
            list-style: none;
            position: relative;
            float: left;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0
        }

        #primary_nav_wrap ul a {
            display: block;
            color: #333;
            text-decoration: none;
            font-weight: 700;
            font-size: 12px;
            line-height: 32px;
            padding: 0 15px;
            font-family: "HelveticaNeue", "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif
        }

        #primary_nav_wrap ul li {
            position: relative;
            float: left;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0
        }

        #primary_nav_wrap ul li.current-menu-item {
            background: #ddd
        }

        #primary_nav_wrap ul li:hover {
            background: #f6f6f6
        }

        #primary_nav_wrap ul ul li {
            float: none;
            width: 200px
        }

        #primary_nav_wrap ul ul a {
            line-height: 120%;
            padding: 10px 15px
        }

        #primary_nav_wrap ul ul ul {
            top: 0;
            left: 100%
        }

        

        #primary_nav_wrap .filho {
            display: none;
            position: absolute;
            top: 100%;
            left: 0;
            background: #fff;
            padding: 0;
        }
        #primary_nav_wrap .pai:hover>.filho {
            display: block;
        }
        

        #primary_nav_wrap .filho .neto ul, 
        #primary_nav_wrap .filho .neto .bisneto ul {
            transform: scaleY(0);
            transform-origin: top;
            transition: transform 0.1ms linear 500ms; /* aqui vc contro o tempo antes do submenu fechar */
            position: absolute;
            top: 100%;
            left: 0;
            background: #fff;
            padding: 0;
        }

        #primary_nav_wrap .filho .neto:hover>ul, 
        #primary_nav_wrap .filho .neto .bisneto:hover>ul {
            transform: scaleY(1);
            transition: transform 0.1ms linear 0s;
        }
        

        #primary_nav_wrap .neto > ul,
        #primary_nav_wrap .bisneto > ul {
            top: 0 !important;
            left: 100% !important;
        }
```

```html
<nav id="primary_nav_wrap">
        <ul>
            <li class="current-menu-item">
                <a href="#">Home</a>
            </li>
            <li class="pai">
                <a href="#">PAI 1</a>
                <ul class="filho">
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">FILHOS</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Gogol</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Nietzsche</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="neto">
                        <a href="#">NETO</a>
                        <ul class="sub-menu">
                            <li>
                                <a href="#">Linspector</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="#">Shakespeare</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="#">Andrade</a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="bisneto">
                                <a href="#">BISNETO</a>
                                <ul class="sub-menu">
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="#">Shingeki No Kyojin</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="#">Shisekai yori</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="#">No game no life</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="#">One Punch Man</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="#">Nanatsu no Tasai</a>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="#">Tolstói</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="#">Platão</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Dostoievski</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Immanuel Kant</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="pai">
                <a href="#">PAI 2</a>
                <ul class="filho">
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">FILHOS2</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="neto">
                        <a href="#">NETO2</a>
                        <ul class="sub-menu">
                            <li class="bisneto">
                                <a href="#">BISNETO2</a>
                                <ul class="sub-menu">
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="#">Shingeki No Kyojin</a>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="pai">
                <a href="#">PAI 3</a>
                <ul class="filho">
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">FILHOS 3</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="neto">
                        <a href="#">NETO 3</a>
                        <ul class="sub-menu">
                            <li>
                                <a href="#">Linspector</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
```

---

***Opção com delay no menu inteiro inclusive nos "pais"***

```css
        html,
        body {
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }


        #primary_nav_wrap {
            margin-top: 15px
        }

        #primary_nav_wrap ul {
            list-style: none;
            position: relative;
            float: left;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0
        }

        #primary_nav_wrap ul a {
            display: block;
            color: #333;
            text-decoration: none;
            font-weight: 700;
            font-size: 12px;
            line-height: 32px;
            padding: 0 15px;
            font-family: "HelveticaNeue", "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif
        }

        #primary_nav_wrap ul li {
            position: relative;
            float: left;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0
        }

        #primary_nav_wrap ul li.current-menu-item {
            background: #ddd
        }

        #primary_nav_wrap ul li:hover {
            background: #f6f6f6
        }

        #primary_nav_wrap ul ul {
            transform: scaleY(0);
            transform-origin: top;
            transition: transform 0.1ms linear 500ms; /* aqui vc contro o tempo antes do submenu fechar */
            position: absolute;
            top: 100%;
            left: 0;
            background: #fff;
            padding: 0
        }

        #primary_nav_wrap ul ul li {
            float: none;
            width: 200px
        }

        #primary_nav_wrap ul ul a {
            line-height: 120%;
            padding: 10px 15px
        }

        #primary_nav_wrap ul ul ul {
            top: 0;
            left: 100%
        }

        #primary_nav_wrap ul li:hover>ul {
            transform: scaleY(1);
            transition: transform 0.1ms linear 0s;
        }
```

```html
<nav id="primary_nav_wrap">
        <ul>
            <li class="current-menu-item">
                <a href="#">Home</a>
            </li>
            <li class="has-children">
                <a href="#">Sub Menu 2</a>
                <ul class="sub-menu">
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Schiller</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Gogol</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Nietzsche</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="has-children">
                        <a href="#">Schoppenhauer</a>
                        <ul class="sub-menu">
                            <li>
                                <a href="#">Linspector</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="#">Shakespeare</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="#">Andrade</a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="has-children">
                                <a href="#">Code Geass</a>
                                <ul class="sub-menu">
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="#">Shingeki No Kyojin</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="#">Shisekai yori</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="#">No game no life</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="#">One Punch Man</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="#">Nanatsu no Tasai</a>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="#">Tolstói</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="#">Platão</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Dostoievski</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Immanuel Kant</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Menu 1</a>
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Sub Menu 1</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Sub Menu 2</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Sub Menu 3</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Sub Menu 4</a>

                        <ul>
                            <li>
                                <a href="#">Deep Menu 1</a>
                                <ul>
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="#">Sub Deep 1</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="#">Sub Deep 2</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="#">Sub Deep 3</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="#">Sub Deep 4</a>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="#">Deep Menu 2</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Sub Menu 5</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Menu 2</a>
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Sub Menu 1</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Sub Menu 2</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Sub Menu 3</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Menu 3</a>
                <ul>
                    <li class="dir">
                        <a href="#">Sub Menu 1</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="dir">
                        <a href="#">Sub Menu 2 THIS IS SO LONG IT MIGHT CAUSE AN ISSEUE BUT MAYBE NOT?</a>
                        <ul>
                            <li>
                                <a href="#">Category 1</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="#">Category 2</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="#">Category 3</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="#">Category 4</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="#">Category 5</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Sub Menu 3</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Sub Menu 4</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Sub Menu 5</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Menu 4</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Menu 5</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Menu 6</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Contact Us</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
```

Comment: Eu estava vendo algo no codepen, que utiliza js, com timer, funcionando até certo ponto, o problema é eu esperava que o menu fechasse quando o mouse fosse movido para a navegação principal. https://codepen.io/team/css-tricks/pen/myLByd

Comment: Então pelo que entendi vc quer o delay só nos sub-menus e não no menu principal é isso?

Comment: Rapaz, acho que sim, se eu abro um Item com sub-menu, mas movo o mouse para outro item fora desse sub-menu, mas para a navegação principal, a "nav" eu esperava que o delay fosse parado.

Comment: Eu vejo um futuro nessa solução simples ** Unhover Intent in JS ** do CSS-TRICKS no codepen. É quase perfeito. O que pode ser feito para que ele seja mais eficiente é: O Dropdown deve manter o delay, inclusive no dropdown do dropdown. Mas o delay deve terminar caso o mouse vá para outro item da nav principal.

Comment: @JohnQuimera cara eu precisei dar uma fritada aqui mas resolvi, agora fiz de uma forma que só os sub-menus tem o delay. Os itens principais do menu não tem delay. Também coloquei um nome nas classes para facilitar a organização facilitar a compreensão da ordem das ul > li

Comment: É justamente isso. Isso resolve um pouco, há uma superioridade nas soluções que encontrei até agora em css. Eu só notei que há um atraso, não no delay propriamente dito, isso está perfeito. Eu falo na transição entre os items pai. Eu passo o mouse em um item e abre um dropdown, e então eu vou lá em cima com o mouso em outro item com dropdown. Se o delay entre os dropdowns PAI terminasse no momento em outro PAI é hover, seria perfeito.  Imagino que talvez isso seja algo que pode ser resolvido com js não?

Comment: @JohnQuimera mas se vc tirar o mouse para fora do submenu, digo, para outra parte da tela que não o menu ele já some na hora... Cara meu forte não é JS, na verdade não manjo nada de JS e a única coisa que consegui fazer é sumir com o neto ou bizneto, porem não consigo traze-lo de volta no segundo hover. Eu tentei fazer um .mouseleave com jQuery, mas não rolou.

Comment: Compreendo. Eu tive uma ideia para esse seu codigo, só precisar colocar o timeout nisso aqui https://stackoverflow.com/a/13811736/2705271

Comment: Eu adicionei uma resposta, que utiliza jquery para atrasar a remoção da classe do sub-menu. Ainda não está perfeito, é algo que pode ser melhorado.

Comment: @JohnQuimera é ficou interessante tb, se vc já for usar o jquery em outras coisas do site ai pode valer a pena, mas se for usar jQuery só por causa do menu ai eu ficara com a opção de usar apenas o css.

Comment: De fato, já pretendo usar outras coisas em jquery, apesar de que tomei um gosto pelo o DOM, como essa solução ainda não está completa, e é aparentemente simples, acredito que possa ser melhorada JS puro ou jquery mesmo, acho que é algo que o @dvd faria com muita facilidade.

Answer (score 1):

Essa é uma solução básica quase perfeita em jquery, utilizando o **setTimeout**

**Referências:**

https://stackoverflow.com/a/18514406/2705271

http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/5G3BH/16/

```js
jQuery(function($) {
    "use strict";

var x = '',y = '';
$('#primary_nav_wrap ul > li').mouseenter(function (e1) {
    var thisItem = $(this);
    clearTimeout(x);

    y = setTimeout(function (e1) {

        if ($(thisItem).children().hasClass('show-the-menu')) {
            return;
        } else {
            $(thisItem).children().addClass('show-the-menu');
            $(thisItem).siblings().children().removeClass('show-the-menu');
        }

    }, 0);

}).mouseleave(function (e2) {
    var thisItem = $(this);
    clearTimeout(y);
    x = setTimeout(function (e2) {
        if (!$(thisItem).children().hasClass('show-the-menu')) {
            return;
        } else {
            $(thisItem).children().removeClass('show-the-menu');
        }
    }, 1000);
});
  })
```

```css
#primary_nav_wrap
{
 margin-top:15px
}

#primary_nav_wrap ul
{
 list-style:none;
 position:relative;
 float:left;
 margin:0;
 padding:0
}

#primary_nav_wrap ul a
{
 display:block;
 color:#333;
 text-decoration:none;
 font-weight:700;
 font-size:12px;
 line-height:32px;
 padding:0 15px;
 font-family:"HelveticaNeue","Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif
}

#primary_nav_wrap ul li
{
 position:relative;
 float:left;
 margin:0;
 padding:0
}

#primary_nav_wrap ul li.current-menu-item
{
 background:#ddd
}

#primary_nav_wrap ul li:hover
{
 background:#f6f6f6
}

#primary_nav_wrap ul ul
{
 position:absolute;
 top:100%;
 left:0;
 background:#fff;
 padding:0
}

#primary_nav_wrap ul ul li
{
 float:none;
 width:200px
}

#primary_nav_wrap ul ul a
{
 line-height:120%;
 padding:10px 15px
}

#primary_nav_wrap ul ul ul
{
 top:0;
 left:100%
}

#primary_nav_wrap .sub-menu {
    display: none;
}
#primary_nav_wrap ul li:hover > ul,
#primary_nav_wrap ul .sub-menu.show-the-menu {
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav id="primary_nav_wrap">
<ul>
  <li class="has-children"><a href="#">Parent A</a>
    <ul class="sub-menu">
      <li class="has-children"><a href="#">Sub a1</a>
          <ul class="sub-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Item a1.1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Item a1.2</a></li>
      <li class="has-children"><a href="#">SUB SUB 2</a>
          <ul class="sub-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Item a1.1</a></li>
      <li class="has-children"><a href="#">Sub SUB SUB 3</a>
          <ul class="sub-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Item a1.1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Item a1.2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Item a1.3</a></li>
        </ul> 
      </li>
            <li><a href="#">Item a1.2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Item a1.3</a></li>
        </ul> 
      </li>
            <li><a href="#">Item a1.3</a></li>
        </ul> 
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Sub a2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Sub a3</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="has-children"><a href="#">Parent B</a>
    <ul class="sub-menu">
      <li><a href="#">Sub b1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Sub b2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Sub b3</a></li>
    </ul> 
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">No Sub Menu</a></li>
</ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: @dvd o que você acha disso? Como podemos melhorar esse código?